# Saving the result of a linq query to an XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

Here is the original xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <setup>
        <cap>33</cap>
    </setup>
    <setup>
        <cap>dd</cap>
    </setup>
</configuration>
```

In the example below I delete the node where cap equals to 33

```
Dim Cap As integer = 33
Dim query = From q In XElement.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\sample.xml").Elements("setup") _
            Where q.Value = Cap _
            Select q
For Each q In query
    If Cap = q.Element("cap").Value Then q.Remove()
Next
```

Now how can I write back the result of the query to the .xml file? Like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <setup>
        <cap>dd</cap>
    </setup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can just create a new XDocument with the data. (C# syntax, but easily converted...)

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("configuration", query));
doc.Save(file);
```

Comment: Too close... i tried something like   Dim doc As XDocument
        doc.Add(<onfiguration><%= query %></configuration>)
        doc.Save(... but it didn't work out! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about using XPath:

```
Imports System.Xml.XPath

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim doc = XDocument.Load("foo.xml")
        doc.XPathSelectElements("//setup/cap[text() = 'dd']/..").Remove()
        Console.WriteLine(doc)
    End Sub

End Module
```